# Calculating the Count of every pair product for every Order Divided by the number of every product and insert the result in correlation table

Tags: sql-server, r, t-sql

Hello Every one I have a historical data-set of sales and i want to create a query which calculate the correlation between the products by calculating the number of orders which has every pair products and then dividing this number over the number of all orders which Has one of this pair, As Ex ( If i want to calculate the correlation between Product "A" and Product "B" then i will count all orders which has "A" & "B" in the same order and then dividing this count over the orders which has Product "A" only [this will differ if i want to get the correlation between "B" & "A"]).
and i want to store this result in a table of correlation As Shown in the Flowing image[image]

and this is a sample of 300 Row from my data

```
structure(list(ï..OrderId = c(137413L, 137413L, 137413L, 137413L, 
137413L, 137413L, 137413L, 137413L, 137413L, 137413L, 137413L, 
137413L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 
136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 136729L, 
137260L, 137260L, 137260L, 137260L, 137260L, 137260L, 137260L, 
137260L, 137260L, 137260L, 137429L, 137429L, 137429L, 137429L, 
137429L, 137429L, 137429L, 137429L, 137429L, 137902L, 137902L, 
137902L, 137902L, 137902L, 137902L, 137902L, 137974L, 137974L, 
138837L, 138837L, 138837L, 138837L, 138837L, 138837L, 139424L, 
139424L, 139424L, 139424L, 139424L, 139424L, 139424L, 139424L, 
139424L, 139642L, 139642L, 139642L, 139642L, 139642L, 139642L, 
139642L, 140676L, 140676L, 140676L, 140676L, 140676L, 140676L, 
140938L, 140938L, 140938L, 140938L, 140938L, 140938L, 140938L, 
140938L, 140938L, 140938L, 141302L, 141302L, 141302L, 141302L, 
141302L, 141302L, 137302L, 137302L, 137302L, 137302L, 138297L, 
138297L, 138297L, 138297L, 138297L, 138297L, 138297L, 138297L, 
138297L, 138297L, 138297L, 138297L, 138297L, 134444L, 134444L, 
134444L, 141134L, 141134L, 141134L, 141134L, 134468L, 134468L, 
131965L, 131965L, 131965L, 131965L, 131965L, 131965L, 131965L, 
131965L, 131965L, 135722L, 135722L, 135722L, 135722L, 135722L, 
135722L, 135722L, 135722L, 135722L, 135722L, 135722L, 135722L, 
135722L, 135722L, 139444L, 139444L, 139444L, 139444L, 139444L, 
139444L, 131866L, 131866L, 131866L, 131866L, 131866L, 131866L, 
131866L, 136078L, 136078L, 136078L, 136078L, 136078L, 136078L, 
136078L, 136078L, 136078L, 136078L, 136078L, 136078L, 136078L, 
137419L, 137419L, 137419L, 137419L, 137419L, 137419L, 137419L, 
137419L, 137419L, 137419L, 137419L, 137419L, 139214L, 139214L, 
139214L, 139214L, 139214L, 139214L, 131997L, 131997L, 131997L, 
131997L, 139482L, 139482L, 139482L, 139482L, 139482L, 139482L, 
139482L, 136066L, 136066L, 136066L, 136066L, 136066L, 136066L, 
136066L, 136610L, 136610L, 136610L, 136610L, 136610L, 137352L, 
137352L, 137352L, 137352L, 137352L, 137352L, 137352L, 137352L, 
133358L, 133358L, 133358L, 134522L, 134522L, 134522L, 134522L, 
134522L, 134522L, 134522L, 134522L, 131481L, 131481L, 131481L, 
131918L, 131918L, 131918L, 131918L, 135758L, 135758L, 135758L, 
135758L, 135678L, 135678L, 135678L, 135678L, 135678L, 135678L, 
135678L, 135678L, 135678L, 131986L, 131986L, 131986L, 131986L, 
131986L, 131986L, 131986L, 139468L, 139468L, 139468L, 139468L, 
139468L, 139468L, 139468L, 139468L, 139468L, 139468L, 139533L, 
139533L, 139533L, 139533L, 139533L, 139533L, 139533L, 139533L, 
139533L, 131950L, 137540L, 137540L, 137540L, 137540L, 137540L, 
137540L, 137540L, 138021L, 138021L, 138021L, 138021L, 138021L, 
138021L, 138021L, 138021L, 138021L, 134490L, 134490L, 134490L, 
134490L, 134490L), Items = structure(c(29L, 27L, 79L, 35L, 50L, 
77L, 32L, 80L, 24L, 60L, 20L, 44L, 46L, 47L, 27L, 68L, 14L, 35L, 
22L, 77L, 15L, 73L, 80L, 60L, 42L, 29L, 27L, 68L, 51L, 10L, 35L, 
22L, 73L, 62L, 60L, 27L, 51L, 10L, 37L, 35L, 22L, 62L, 80L, 60L, 
47L, 68L, 51L, 10L, 22L, 77L, 73L, 51L, 10L, 18L, 47L, 73L, 24L, 
60L, 20L, 18L, 29L, 47L, 17L, 35L, 77L, 11L, 73L, 78L, 46L, 18L, 
29L, 9L, 17L, 35L, 73L, 46L, 18L, 9L, 17L, 35L, 73L, 18L, 29L, 
27L, 22L, 50L, 19L, 73L, 13L, 1L, 7L, 46L, 8L, 80L, 24L, 60L, 
61L, 48L, 64L, 10L, 6L, 29L, 47L, 27L, 28L, 10L, 22L, 15L, 73L, 
62L, 24L, 60L, 20L, 58L, 66L, 67L, 43L, 38L, 36L, 74L, 70L, 74L, 
37L, 74L, 37L, 22L, 77L, 34L, 15L, 73L, 62L, 67L, 46L, 53L, 63L, 
57L, 74L, 48L, 27L, 17L, 14L, 15L, 73L, 12L, 67L, 43L, 18L, 29L, 
14L, 35L, 32L, 73L, 46L, 18L, 52L, 19L, 62L, 71L, 23L, 14L, 35L, 
34L, 19L, 73L, 13L, 43L, 39L, 24L, 75L, 20L, 3L, 41L, 29L, 27L, 
68L, 64L, 14L, 35L, 11L, 19L, 15L, 73L, 43L, 45L, 65L, 55L, 67L, 
61L, 58L, 40L, 57L, 74L, 31L, 73L, 69L, 65L, 30L, 73L, 56L, 49L, 
61L, 74L, 19L, 72L, 13L, 43L, 26L, 41L, 46L, 27L, 68L, 60L, 41L, 
74L, 27L, 37L, 14L, 73L, 43L, 60L, 41L, 74L, 32L, 67L, 4L, 29L, 
59L, 21L, 25L, 76L, 73L, 43L, 57L, 74L, 62L, 74L, 54L, 33L, 2L, 
15L, 73L, 62L, 80L, 59L, 21L, 25L, 27L, 14L, 15L, 73L, 43L, 80L, 
57L, 31L, 32L, 19L, 15L, 73L, 72L, 46L, 16L, 18L, 29L, 5L, 14L, 
35L, 22L, 73L, 61L, 46L, 18L, 29L, 5L, 14L, 35L, 22L, 73L, 61L, 
74L, 46L, 18L, 29L, 27L, 73L, 62L, 43L, 68L, 65L, 64L, 10L, 37L, 
17L, 11L, 61L, 70L, 59L, 21L, 25L, 76L, 14L), .Label = c(" Green Beans", 
"Apricot", "Arugula", "Arugula old", "Autumn Royal Grape", "Avocado", 
"Baladi Cabbage", "Baladi Garlic", "Banati Grape", "Barshomi Figs", 
"Black Eggplant", "Broccoli", "Cantaloupe", "Capsicum", "Carrot", 
"Cauliflower", "Chili Pepper", "Classic Eggplant", "Cooking Potato", 
"Coriander", "Coriander old", "Cucumber", "Deluxe Dried Dates", 
"Dill", "Dill old", "Dried Dates", "Flame Grape", "Fons Mango", 
"frying Potato", "Gala Apple", "Golden Apple", "Golden Onion", 
"Granny Apple", "Grape Leaves", "Green pepper", "Guava", "Hot Pepper", 
"Imported Peach", "Japanese Plum", "Lebanese Apple", "Local Apple", 
"Local Celery ", "Local Cucumber", "Local Eggplant", "Local Hot Pepper", 
"Local Lemon", "Local Pear", "Melon", "Mint", "Molokhia", "Momtaza Owais Mango", 
"Morket Tangerine", "Mushroom (200G) old", "Nectarine Peach", 
"Nems Watermelon (KG)", "Okra", "Orange For Juice", "Owais Mango", 
"Parsle old", "Parsley", "Red Globe Grape", "Red Onion", "Red Radish old", 
"Sadeeka Mango", "Sokkary Mango", "Strawberry", "Sugary Peach", 
"Superior Grape", "Sweet Potato", "Syrian plum", "Tamr hendi", 
"Taro", "Tomato", "Watermelon ( per KG)", "White Cabbage", "White Cabbage Old", 
"White Eggplant ", "Zaghlol Dates", "Zebdaya Mango", "Zucchini"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ï..OrderId", "Items"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-300L))
```

Comment: Could you provide data with `dput`: `dput(data)` and paste it here?

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to understand why

Comment: Is `r` relevant for the sql query?

Comment: the first cell Mango vs Mango should also be 1?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Mango Vs Should be 1 yes because the ratio of getting "A" With "A" will be 100%

Comment: Check this one. would be enough to calculate your correlation http://rextester.com/NRQR82162 ... do you know how do a PIVOT ?

Comment: How can you get negative values?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thanks, its a useful idea but there's a problem with it which is the final result of dividing the pair count over the single count , and the other problem is related with generating this code with more than 40000 order so you can help to solve that ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza negative values refers to the negative correlation and its has an important meaning in the statistics and its meaning that ( If "A" has a large negative correlation with "B" that meaning that the chance of purchasing "A" is decreasing when "B" added to the cart for example) but in this case its not important

Comment: OK .. Im just saying the formula you provide only generate positive value  and doesnt match your sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Calculate the total orders for each product
2. Pair each product with every one else
3. Join the pair with orders to find which orders have both products
4. join all together to have `COUNT(A&B)` and `COUNT(A)`

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/DDA89324)**

```
WITH products as (
    SELECT [OtherLangDescription], COUNT(*) as orders_total
    FROM Orders 
    GROUP BY [OtherLangDescription]
), correlation as (
    SELECT p1.[OtherLangDescription] as p1,
           p1.orders_total as total1,
           p2.[OtherLangDescription] as p2,
           p2.orders_total as total2    
    FROM products p1
    CROSS JOIN products p2
), dual_products as (
    SELECT p1, p2, COUNT (o1.OrderID) as pair_orders_total
    FROM correlation c
    JOIN orders o1
      ON c.p1 = o1.[OtherLangDescription]
    JOIN orders o2
      ON c.p2 = o2.[OtherLangDescription]
     AND o1.orderID = o2.orderID
    GROUP BY p1, p2
)
SELECT c.*, 
       d.pair_orders_total,
       d.pair_orders_total * 1.0 / c.total1 as correlation   
FROM correlation c
JOIN dual_products d
  ON c.p1 = d.p1
 AND c.p2 = d.p2
```

If you save the previous result as table Result the pivot is like this:

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/PUK32997)**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(p2) 
            FROM Results c 
            GROUP BY p2
            ORDER BY p2  
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')                             
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT p1, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select p1
                    , p2
                    , correlation
                from Results
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(correlation)
                for p2 in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            ORDER BY p1'

execute(@query);
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I update the query with the correlation calculation (as I understand it). What is the problem with 4000 orders?

Comment: Unbelievable! its working Thanks very much, But i has a problem of duplicating the result for every execution  so can i solve that ?

Comment: Sorry dont understand what you mean

Comment: I want to use this query on the data which changing every day so that i want to execute this query every day may be, but in my data when i do that the total values its increasing every execute because its adding the existing value to the new value.

Comment: `DROP` the table Result before running the query?

Comment: there's no another way ?

Comment: `TRUNCATE` the table? I dont see the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159164/discussion-between-abdalmomen-elsayed-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).